# Using the Half Angle Identity to convert cosine into a sine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am struggling with an identity that my professor has used to find something in terms of t. The problem is essentially find when the particle stops moving given parameter:
$x=\cos(4t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$.

I know I need to take the derivative of both, add them squared and set it equal to 0. My problem is I am left with
$$16\sin^2(4t) + \cos^2(t) = 0.$$
How can I turn cosine into some form of sine? His explanation in class left much to be desired. Thanks!

Comment: In the world of real numbers, $a^2+b^2=0$ if an only if $a=0$ and $b=0$

Comment: With the above comment, observe that $\cos^2(t)=0$ if and only if $t=\frac{k\pi}{2}$ where $k$ is an odd integer. And observe that $4t=2k\pi$, and so $\sin^2(4t)=0$. Thus, your expression will be $0$ for all $t=\frac{k\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The second answer really helped clarify this. I kept using the cosine of 1 instead of $pi/2$